# Date time format in react js and moment.js in a Calendar

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd, date-formatting, react-big-calendar

Basically i'm creating a calendar with events plugin and for that using react-big-calendar. I am able to create usestate to add events and show in calendar but whenever I put the start and end date with time coordinates it doesn't show the event where when I just put the start , end date without time coordinates it will show it.

Kinda confuse here whats happening cause when using the hardcore value of events it showing the events without even adding time. Need assistance.

**Whole Calendar component**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./CalendarNew.css"
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import { Badge } from 'antd';
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { DatePicker, Space } from 'antd';
import { Checkbox } from 'antd';
import { Input } from 'antd';

import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment'

const now = new Date();
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)

function CalendarNew() {

    const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [pickerDate, setPickerDate] = useState(null)
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null)
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null)




    const realEvents = [{
        id: 0,
        title: titles,
        location: locations,
        start: new Date(startDate),
        end: new Date(endDate),
        description: description,

    }]



    const events = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'All Day Event very long title',
            allDay: true,
            start: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 20, 20),
            end: new Date(2021, 8, 3, 0, 20, 20),
            location: 'melbourne',
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: new Date(2021, 8, 7),
            end: new Date(2021, 8, 10),
            location: 'sydney',
        },


    ]

    // for PopUp
    const showModal = () => {
        setVisible(true);
    };


    const handleCancel = () => {
        console.log('Clicked cancel button');
        setVisible(false);
    };




    const handleOk = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        // setTitle("");
        // setLocation("");
        // setDescription("");
        // setPickerDate(new Date())
        setStartDate(pickerDate[0].format('YYYY, M, D, h,MM,ss'))
        setEndDate(pickerDate[1].format('YYYY, M, D,h,MM,ss'))
        console.log("Title = ", title, ',Location = ', location, ',Description = ', description, "Daterange =", pickerDate[0].format('YYYY, M, D,h,MM,ss'))
        setVisible(false);


    };


    // title eventListner
    const titleChange = (event) => {
        setTitle(event.target.value)
    }
    // location eventListner
    const locationChange = (event) => {
        setLocation(event.target.value)
    }
    // description eventListner
    const descriptionsChange = (event) => {
        setDescription(event.target.value)
    }
    // range picker eventListner
    const dateChange = (dateString) => {
        setPickerDate(dateString)
    }
    console.log(title)
    ///console.log("range picker start date", pickerDate[0])
    console.log("range picker end date", endDate)

    return (
        <div>
            <Calendar
                localizer={localizer}
                events={realEvents}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                style={{ height: 500 }}
                
            />
            {/* PopUp */}
            <Modal
                centered={true}
                title="Event's"
                visible={visible}
                maskClosable={true}


                visible={visible}
                onCancel={handleCancel}

                footer={[
                    <Button onClick={handleCancel}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>,
                    <Button onClick={handleOk} form="popup_form" key="submit" htmlType="submit" type="primary">
                        Ok
                    </Button>
                ]}

            >
                <div className="form-popup">
                    <form id="popup_form">
                        <div className="row-1">
                            <div className="title">
                                <TextField
                                    style={{ width: '195px' }}
                                    id="title"
                                    name="title"
                                    label="Title"
                                    value={title}
                                    onChange={titleChange}

                                    placeholder={'Title of event'}
                                    variant="standard"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="location">
                                <TextField
                                    style={{ width: '200px' }}
                                    id="location"
                                    name="location"
                                    label="Location"
                                    value={location}
                                    onChange={locationChange}
                                    placeholder={'Location of event'}
                                    variant="standard"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row-2">
                            <div className="start-calendar">
                                <Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
                                    <RangePicker
                                        id="date-picker"
                                        name="date_picker"
                                        value={pickerDate}
                                        onChange={dateChange}
                                        format="YYYY-M-D HH:mm:ss"
                                        placeholder={['Start date', 'End date']}
                                        style={{ width: '420px' }}
                                        size={'large'} />
                                </Space>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row-3'>
                            <div className='checkbox'>
                                <Checkbox
                                    id="all_day"
                                    name="all_day"
                                >
                                    All day
                                </Checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row-4'>
                            <div className='description'>
                                <label>
                                    <TextField
                                        style={{ width: '420px' }}
                                        id="description"
                                        name="description"
                                        label="Description"
                                        value={description}
                                        onChange={descriptionChange}
                                        multiline
                                        rows={1}
                                        placeholder={'description of event'}
                                        variant="standard"
                                    />
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CalendarNew;
```

**Output using state without time coordinates**

[showing the events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kf0C.png)

**Output using state with time coordinates**
To add time coordinates, I'm setting startDate,endDate state to:

```
setStartDate(pickerDate[0].format('YYYY, M, D, h,MM,ss')) 

setEndDate(pickerDate[1].format('YYYY, M, D,h,MM,ss'))
```

[image is here but no event showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Iwl.png)

**Output using hardcode data with time coordinates**
Using the object named events in the code

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUH8K.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all dates in React-Big-Calendar are true JS Date objects. Even those you use on an Event. When constructing an event, make sure to use `Date`s for your start and end dates, especially when you add them to the `events` used in the prop.

Comment: i think i have done that in the file and I actually get the events when I enter the date value but when I try to add time value with it, the event doesn’t show. do you have a NY idea why it's happening like that?

Comment: But the issue is in trying to format dates for start and end when you don't need to. It appears that your date picker must already return `moment` values (otherwise you wouldn't be using `format`). So you don't really need to format them, so much as get the value as a JS `Date` with `pickerDate[0].toDate()`. Then you can just reference that directly in your `realEvents` without having to call the Date constructors.

Answer (score 0):

So, the bug was in the format part itself in the state. Correct answer:

```
setStartDate(pickerDate[0].format('YYYY, M, D, HH:mm:ss')) 

setEndDate(pickerDate[1].format('YYYY, M, D, HH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sharanjeet Singh, you should accept this as the best answer.

Comment: hi, thanks for the message, this answer is also working but I think the first answer by steve is more accurate and professional.